# How to deal with Elasticsearch failures when replicating from Couchbase?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I have cross-datacenter replication (XDCR) setup to replicate data from a Couchbase bucket to an Elasticsearch index. Some times, however, Elasticsearch fails and needs to be restarted. During this time any changes to the Couchbase bucket are not replicated. Is there a recommended way of dealing with this? Ideally, once Elasticsearch restarts the data added to Couchbase in the interim gets replcated successfully.

Comment: Did you add any template? if yes show me the template.